# All I have is an RDP file and IP address. How do I remotely connect using them?

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, remmina, remote-login

I am trying to [access one of my school's Windows 7 machines remotely](http://www.engin.umich.edu/caen/connect/virtualsites.html). For this, they provide an RDP file to establish the connection with after you fill out connection settings on an online form (remote desktop size, local resources, etc.), under the assumption that you are using Windows or Mac. They also provide an IP address and port number in case I "choose to manually connect" to my assigned machine, but they provide no further instructions on how to use it.

I would like to be able to connect to this machine remotely using Ubuntu. Preferably, I'd like to try using the new [Remote Login feature in 12.10](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/ubuntu-12-10-login-screen-adds-remote-desktop-access) to connect, although I guess I could try Remmina if that won't work. I tried naively entering my assigned IP address and port, and my school username and password, into both [UCCS](https://uccs.landscape.canonical.com/) for Remote Login and into Remmina for a new RDP connection, but neither would let me connect (the former hangs at my laptop's login screen for a couple minutes before saying the password is incorrect, while the latter can't establish a connection at all).

What step-by-step instructions should I use to make a connection based on what I was given?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way may be to ask your school administrators to give the information required to connect.

However the dot RDP file is a plain text file. Open it in Gedit or your favourite text editor.

It is a bit cryptic but key information is in :-
full address:  Network name or IP Address of target
username: logon user name.